# mikrotik total traffic limit

Tags: bandwidth-control, mikrotik

I am running PPPoe in mikrotik.... I can use speed rate limit per user but i want to limit of total traffic per month.... for example i want to limit a user for 10GB traffic at 1mbps speed after 10GB used client can not connect using pppoe please help me to do this

Also i want to track user traffic per login.... so that i can get details that how much traffic passed in a single login

thank for your help

Answer (score 2):

Use User Manager - [here](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/User_Manager) is the documentation how to set it up for PPP.

In [user data](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/User_Manager/Users), you can set the download limit (and upload limit, or the sum).

I don't know if there is an automatic way to reset the counters, but you can script that, to happen on the first of the month (or whenever).

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what Radius is designed to do. Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting. However, proper Radius usage is not trivial, and not really a concept that could be explained in one answer. I can highly recommend [freeRADIUS](http://freeradius.org/), it is an excellent piece of software, and many people are using it to do what you are requesting.

Comment: I have search lots about RADIUS.. I think RADIUS is not easy thing to implement...

Comment: You are correct, it isn't easy to configure, mostly because it is an extremely powerful tool, there are quite a few tutorials about setting it up to work with mikrotik. Have a look at radman : http://www.dmasoftlab.com/cont/radman

Comment: Mikrotik has a radius server built in called user manager.